# What is the equivalent of pandas.cut() in PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

[`pandas.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut) is used to bin values into discrete intervals. For instance,

```
pd.cut(
    np.array([0.2, 0.25, 0.36, 0.55, 0.67, 0.78]), 
    3, 
    include_lowest=True, 
    right=False
)

Out[9]: 
[[0.2, 0.393), [0.2, 0.393), [0.2, 0.393), [0.393, 0.587), [0.587, 0.781), [0.587, 0.781)]
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [[0.2, 0.393) < [0.393, 0.587) < [0.587, 0.781)]
```

How can I achieve the same in PySpark? I had a look to [`QuantileDiscretizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.QuantileDiscretizer.html) but it's definitely not the equivalent of `pd.cut()` as it does not return the intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RDD.histogram](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.histogram.html) is a similar function in Spark.

Assume that the data is contained in a dataframe with the column `col1`.

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
| 0.2|
|0.25|
|0.36|
|0.55|
|0.67|
|0.78|
+----+
```

```python
h = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).histogram(3) #change 3 to the number of expected intervals

bins = [ (x, h[0][i+1]) for i,x in enumerate(h[0][:-1])]

def label(bin):
    return f"'{bin[0]:5.2f} - {bin[1]:5.2f}'"

e = "case "
for bin in bins[:-1]:
    e += f"when col1 >= {bin[0]} and col1 < {bin[1]} then {label(bin)} "
e += f"else {label(bins[-1])} end as bin"

df.selectExpr("col1", e).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+
|col1|          bin|
+----+-------------+
| 0.2| 0.20 -  0.39|
|0.25| 0.20 -  0.39|
|0.36| 0.20 -  0.39|
|0.55| 0.39 -  0.59|
|0.67| 0.59 -  0.78|
|0.78| 0.59 -  0.78|
+----+-------------+
```

`bins` contains the intervals as tuples:

```
[(0.2, 0.39333333333333337),
 (0.39333333333333337, 0.5866666666666667),
 (0.5866666666666667, 0.78)]
```

Comment: Does this mean that if I already know the buckets/intervals, I can skip histogram and then do the `CASE WHEN...` ?

Comment: @Tokyo yes, you are right. When you know the intervals, you can simply use the for-loop

Comment: Does this mean, in each bin, the number of items will be the same?

Comment: @pnv no, all bins cover the same share of the interval between the minimal and the maximal value of the input data and therefore have the same length (0.1933..)